# $X$ and $1 - X$ are identically distributed

Tags: probability, self-learning

I have a two-fold goal for this question.  First, I'm trying my hand at making hypotheses and proving them as far as I can.  I want to understand the limits of proof, not just the techniques.  Second, I'm hoping to find slick ways to prove things.

Suppose that $X$ and $Y = 1 - X$ are identically distributed continuous random variables.  It is my hypothesis that both $X$ and $Y$ are uniformly distributed on the unit interval.  My attempt to prove it goes something like this:

(On the relation between $F_X(x)$ and $F_X(1 - x)$): Since $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed, $F_X(x) = P(X<x) = P(Y<x) = P(1 - X < x) = P(1 - x < X) = 1 - P(X < 1 - x) = 1 - F_X(1 - x)$.

(Concerning the density of $X$): Differentiate to show that $f_X(x) = f_X(1 - x)$

(Concerning the range of $X$):  Now suppose $x = 1$.  Then, clearly, $0 = 1 - x < 1 \leq x = 1$.  Since $F_X$ is monotone increasing, we have the relation $1 - F_X(1) = F_X(0) \leq F_X(1) = 1 - F_X(0)$.

This is where I'm getting stuck.  I'd like to show that the range is $[0,1]$ (up to measurability).  To me, it feels like there aren't enough constraints on $F_X$ to prove that $X$ the range of $X$ is $[0,1]$.  Similarly, I'm not sure there are enough constraints to prove that $f_X$ is constant.

What are your thoughts?  Is there a slick proof?  Even a hint for a property of $F_X$ or $f_X$ I might have missed would be extremely useful.

Comment: "Suppose that X and Y=1−X are identically distributed continuous random variables. It is my hypothesis that both X and Y are uniformly distributed on the unit interval. My attempt to prove it goes something like this..." Please define "it" in "My attempt to prove it" (there seems to be only hypotheses here).

Comment: Why assume that you are dealing with random variables with support on [0,1]?  And even if you do make that restriction, clearly, any symmetric distribution about 1/2 will work.

Comment: @Did: substitute "It is my conjecture that both $X$ and $Y$ are uniformly distributed on the unit interval"

Comment: Then the conjecture is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition says that the density function of $X$ is symmetric about $\frac{1}{2}$, and **no more**.

If $X=\frac{1}{2}+W$, where $W$ is **any** random variable which is symmetric about $w=0$, then $X$ and $Y$ will have the same distribution.

Comment: Aha, that does explain why there was so much "wiggle room" in my constraints (especially on $F_X$).  Can you explain how you came to the conclusion for symmetry?

Comment: $1-X$ has the same distribution as $X$ is a pure symmetry statement. If it had said $Z$ and $-Z$ have the same distribution, you would have recognized the symmetry instantly. Symmetry about $\frac{1}{2}$ is less obvious to the eye, although it is a frequent phenomenon. What went wrong is that you started computing with the cdf. The geometry comes first.

Comment: Thank you.  I will have to think about that a little bit, but I do see your point about $Z$ and $-Z$.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition on the density is a sufficient condition for $X$ and $1-X$ to be identically distributed, so if $X$ has a density $ \propto x(1-x), 0 < x < 1 $, then $1-X$ will have the same distribution

Comment: How does this answer the question? Upvoters: any explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $g$ is any probability density function on the real line.

Let $h(x) = g(1-x)$.

Let $f(x) = \dfrac{h(x)+g(x)}{2}$.

The $f$ is a probability density function. And
$$
f(1-x) = \frac{h(1-x)+g(1-x)}{2} = \frac{g(1-(1-x))+h(x)}{2} = \frac{g(x)+h(x)}{2} = f(x).
$$

So there are plenty of probability density functions satisfying the equation $f(x)=f(1-x)$.

All of them give probability distributions symmetric about $1/2$.